# Array prints out wrong numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and I have to make a program that lets the user enter a specified number of test scores and calculate the average, highest, and lowest scores. (It doesn't have to check if values are between 1 and 100.) For some reason, when it goes to print out the average score and sum of the scores, it just prints out random exponential numbers that are never the same. I haven't gotten to printing out the lowest and highest scores yet since I'm not sure if I'm even doing the average right. Again, I'm new to C++ so I'm sure I messed something up. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int loopLimit = 0; //number of scores or how many times it will loop
double *testScores = {0}; //array scores are stored in

int main () {
    cout << "How many test scores are you entering?" << endl;
     cin >> loopLimit;

     testScores = new double[loopLimit]; //changes array to needed size

     for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++) {
         cout << "Enter test score #" << (i + 1) << endl;
         cin >> *testScores;
     }

    double sum = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    //double max = 0.0; //making these functions later
    //double min = 0.0; 

     sum += testScores[loopLimit];
     average = sum / loopLimit;
     //Sum is here for testing purposes at the moment

     cout << "Sum = " << sum << " Average = " << average << endl;

     return 0; 
}
```

**Example output 1:**

```
How many test scores are you entering?
3
Enter test score #1
100
Enter test score #2
100
Enter test score #3
100
Sum = 8.29874e-310 Average = 2.76625e-310
```

**Example output 2:**

```
How many test scores are you entering?
3
Enter test score #1
100
Enter test score #2
100
Enter test score #3
100
Sum = 8.94176e-310 Average = 2.98059e-310
```

**Expected output:**

```
How many test scores are you entering?
3
Enter test score #1
100
Enter test score #2
100
Enter test score #3
100
Sum = 300.0 Average = 100.0
```

I've been at this all week, and I honestly got nothing at this point.

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: `cin >> *(testScores + i)` _but_ you should be using `vector`, not c-style arrays

Comment: This line doesn't do what you wanted: `sum += testScores[loopLimit];`  It's actually reading from outside the array.

Comment: @Chad: Why would you not use subscripting to write that (`testScores[i]`) ?

Comment: And as Ben says above, you need to calculate the sum as you iterate (or you need to iterate again)

Comment: Yeah -- `cin >> testscores[i]` is better -- sorry, I really try not to think about pointer arithmatic normally

Comment: Arrays don't print anything. *Your code* prints things, and they might be wrong, and they might come from an array, which might be wrong, but none of that is equivalent to 'array prints out wrong numbers'. Be clear. Think clearly. Express youself clearly. It's half the battle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's go over your code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Why are you importing all identifiers in `std::` here? `using namespace std;` is not recommended.

```
int loopLimit = 0; //number of scores or how many times it will loop
double *testScores = {0}; //array scores are stored in
```

Bad: You should avoid global variables unless they're absolutely necessary. 99.9% of the time they're not. These could easily be local variables in `main`.

`testScores` is not an array, it's a pointer. Initializing it with `{0}` is just a weird way of writing `testScores = nullptr;`.

```
int main () {
    cout << "How many test scores are you entering?" << endl;
     cin >> loopLimit;

     testScores = new double[loopLimit]; //changes array to needed size
```

You're using manual memory management here. Not technically wrong, but it would be much easier and less error prone to use a `std::vector` instead.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++) {
         cout << "Enter test score #" << (i + 1) << endl;
         cin >> *testScores;
```

This line stores every input in `*testScores`, i.e. the location pointed to by `testScores`, which corresponds to the first index of the array allocated by `new` above. This means only `testScores[0]` is initialized (ending up containing the last number the user input), every other index is uninitialized.

You should use `cin >> testScores[i]` instead.

```
     }

    double sum = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    //double max = 0.0; //making these functions later
    //double min = 0.0; 

     sum += testScores[loopLimit];
```

This is an invalid memory access. As `testScores` points to a dynamic array of size `loopLimit`, the valid array indices go from `0` to `loopLimit-1`. Therefore `testScores[loopLimit]` accesses memory past the bounds of the array.

Also, it's just one element you're adding here. Even if this were a valid array index, this could would still make no sense. You should loop over all array elements here (like your `for` loop above), or just do this part of the calculation in your other loop. In fact, there's no need to store all numbers in memory if all you're interested in is their sum (which you can compute directly as you're reading the input).

```
     average = sum / loopLimit;
```

`average` is computed from `sum`, which has a garbage value, so it's garbage too.

```
     //Sum is here for testing purposes at the moment

     cout << "Sum = " << sum << " Average = " << average << endl;
```

... and this is why you're getting garbage output.

```
     return 0;
```

Here you're leaking the memory allocated with `new`. This is not really a problem in this case because your program is about to exit anyway, but in general you want `delete[] testScores;` here (unless you use a `std::vector`, which takes care of cleaning up for you).

```
}
```

Comment: Okay, wow. This really helped. But now command line seems to crash whenever a test score is entered. 

for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++) {
   cout << "Enter test score #" << (i + 1) << endl;
   cin >> testScores[i];
  sum += testScores[loopLimit];
  average = sum / loopLimit;
  }

Comment: Think about what each line does.  `testScores[i]` _what does that mean?_  Immediately afterward, you write `sum += testScores[loopLimit]` _what does that mean_?  Are `i` and `loopLimit` the _same value_?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things, first the line

```
     cin >> *testScores;
```

is not storing the test scores in an array (I think this is what you want to do) instead at every iteration the new test score is being stored in the first element i.e testScores[0], rewriting the old value.

Next,
The line

```
sum += testScores[loopLimit];
```

looks outside the array.  This means that you are looking at a random place in memory which probably has junk in it.  That explains why you are seeing random numbers outputted.

Try to fix those two issues.  If you don't need to save the test scores you can away keep a running sum of them, that would eliminate the need to store everything in an array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to write such a messed up code for just calculating average.But here's my approach.
Since you entered `loopLimit` value as `3`.So according to your code,`sum` will contain have the value of `sum[3]`.That is a **garbage value**.Since indexing starts with `0` and not `1`.So your `sum` will have a garbage value and **that is the reason why you are getting such incorrect value**.I have modified your code and it works fine for me.

```
int loopLimit;
cout << "How many test scores are you entering?" << endl;
    cin >> loopLimit;
 double scores[loopLimit];
 double sum=0.0;
 for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++) 
{
         cout << "Enter test score #" << (i + 1) << endl;
         cin >> scores[i];
    sum+=scores[i];
     }
 double avg=sum/loopLimit;
 cout << "Sum = " << sum << " Average = " << avg << endl;
     return 0;
```

Try avoiding using pointers during the early stage of programming as it can really mess up with your brain and can create problems.Try to go for a simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue is that you're doing this

```
double* testScores = {0};
```

which will initialize it to nullptr, potentially letting you read and write garbage data. What you should use instead is probably a dynamic resizing array such as

```
std::vector<double> testScores;
```

and to add a score to the list

```
double inScore = 0;
std::cin >> inScore;
testScores.push_back(inScore); // This adds to the list of scores.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int loopLimit = 0; //number of scores or how many times it will loop
double *testScores = {0}; //array scores are stored in

int main () {

double sum = 0.0;
double average = 0.0;

 cout << "How many test scores are you entering?" << endl;
 cin >> loopLimit;

 testScores = new double[loopLimit]; //changes array to needed size

 for (int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++) {
     cout << "Enter test score #" << (i + 1) << endl;
     cin >> testScores[i];
     sum += testScores[i];
}

 average = sum / loopLimit;

 cout << "Sum = " << sum << " Average = " << average << endl;
 delete [] testScores;
 return 0; 
}
```

*melpomene is right...that pointer "*testScores" wont increment through your for loop so the array occupies garbage also put sum += testScores[i] in the loop to sum your input.*